# Удаление внешнего ключа у таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Как удалить поле таблицы, если оно является внешним ключем ? При таком запросе возникает ошибка:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP COLUMN column;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вначале удалить сам ключ

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_name
```

Где `fk_name` это имя внешнего ключа. Посмотреть его можно выполнив запрос

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table
```

имя будет видно в блоке

```
CONSTRAINT "fk_name" FOREIGN KEY ("my_column") REFERENCES...
```

А потом удалять поле

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN my_column;
```

Comment: А что такое `fk_name` ? Я думал, что `my_column` и есть внешний ключ...

Comment: @faoxis Доуточнил ответ